# Pull data from nested json loop php

Tags: php, json, foreach, nested-loops

Ok, I have been fighting this for two days now!!  Here is my Json structure.
[

```
{
    "uuid":"/random number==",
    "meeting_number":7196503037,
    "host_id":"random number",
    "topic":"My's Personal Meeting Room",
    "start_time":"2015-01-06T22:01:07Z",
    "timezone":"America/Denver",
    "duration":56,
    "total_size":378080,
    "recording_count":1,
    "recording_files":[
        {
            "id":"long number",
            "meeting_id":"/NS90bsSTLeGzo6cT0nwXw==",
            "recording_start":"2015-01-06T22:01:09Z",
            "recording_end":"2015-01-06T22:01:14Z",
            "file_size":378080,
            "play_url":"https://myurl"
        }
    ]
},
```

I am trying to pull the Start Time from the top level array (which is named 'meetings') and the Play Url from the second level array (recording_files).  I am using json_decode to decode the file into arrays.

I have tried many variations found on this site and nothing seems to get to the play url.
VARIATION 1
     $aha = json_decode($response,true);

```
        foreach ($aha['meetings'] as $key => $value){
            foreach($key['recording_files'] as $subkey => $newvalue){


        echo '<p>Time : '.$value['start_time'].'</p>
  <a href="'.$newvalue['play_url'].'">Recording</a><br>';
```

}}
This pulls an invalid argument in foreach.

VARIATION 2
            foreach ($aha['meetings'] as $key => $value){

```
        echo '<p>Time : '.$value['start_time'].'</p>
  <a href="'.$value['play_url'].'">Recording</a><br>';
```

}
This pulls undefined index for play_url.  As does the same code with the reference to ['recording_files'] placed before ['play_url']

VARIATION 3:
Then I tried giving up on the first level and just pulling data from the second level:
             $aha = json_decode($response,true);

```
        foreach ($aha['meetings']['recording_files'] as $key => $value){


        echo '<p>Time : '.$value['recording_start'].'</p>
  <a href="'.$value['play_url'].'">Recording</a><br>';
```

}
That gives me an undefined index on ['recording_files'] and a foreach error.

VARIATION 4.
     $aha = json_decode($response,true);

```
        foreach ($aha['meetings'] as $key => $value){
         $link=$key['recording_files'];

        echo '<p>Time : '.$value['start_time'].'</p>
  <a href="'.$link['play_url'].'">Recording</a><br>';
```

}
This gets me the closest - no errors but no link.  I presume that here the code is seeing the field but just not pulling the data from it...

Please help a newbie json person!!

Comment: Something is wrong with the structure. Opening [ and closing brackets don't match

Comment: You store json in file or via url ?

Comment: @user4035 yes they do... `recording_files` is an array of objects.

Comment: ok, every time you open a square bracket `[` in json you start an array itself. therefore, you should access `$aha['meetings'][0]['recording_files'][0]['play_url']` where you can replace 0 with the corresponding index or acces via a loop. if you unsure where the arrays are, just make a var_dump on `json_decode`

Comment: So using the 0 will pull the data from the 0 record.  I am trying to figure out how to access it through a loop.

Comment: I am pulling the data from an api command

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Edit:**

If your data looks like this :

```
$str = "{\"meetings\":[{
    \"uuid\":\"/random number==\",
    \"meeting_number\":7196503037,
    \"host_id\":\"random number\",
    \"topic\":\"My's Personal Meeting Room\",
    \"start_time\":\"2015-01-06T22:01:07Z\",
    \"timezone\":\"America/Denver\",
    \"duration\":56,
    \"total_size\":378080,
    \"recording_count\":1,
    \"recording_files\":[
        {
            \"id\":\"long number\",
            \"meeting_id\":\"/NS90bsSTLeGzo6cT0nwXw==\",
            \"recording_start\":\"2015-01-06T22:01:09Z\",
            \"recording_end\":\"2015-01-06T22:01:14Z\",
            \"file_size\":378080,
            \"play_url\":\"https://myurl\"
        }
    ]
}]}";


$json = json_decode($str);
$res = $json->{'meetings'};

foreach($res as $keys){
    echo $keys->{'start_time'}."<br>";
    foreach ($keys->{'recording_files'} as $data){
        echo $data->{'play_url'}."<br>";
        echo $data->{'recording_start'}."<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Code that fixed it was: $aha = json_decode($response,true);
            
          foreach ($aha['meetings'] as $key => $value){
          
    
    echo '<p>Time : '.$value['start_time'].'</p>
     <a href="'.$value['recording_files'][0]{'play_url'}.'">Recording</a><br>';
         
}

Answer (score 0):

If there is really an `$aha['meetings']` (you don't show it), then use the value not the key in the second `foreach`:

```
foreach($aha['meetings'] as $value){
    foreach($value['recording_files'] as $newvalue){
```

Answer (score 0):

Final code that fixed it.

```
        $aha = json_decode($response,true);

        foreach ($aha['meetings'] as $key => $value){           

        echo '<p>Time : '.$value['start_time'].'</p>
       <a href="'.$value['recording_files'][0]{'play_url'}.'">Recording</a><br>';}
```

It was just a matter of finding the correct format for referencing the play_url piece. 
Thank you so much to everyone!